# Can not connect to localhost api using React Native app run on real device iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, graphql

I have been developing a React Native with a rails API running on localhost:3000. I have one endpoint only because I am using graphQL with Apollo Client, so I connect to the api with `http://localhost:3000/graphql`.

I am now trying to run the app on my own iPhone - connected via lightning cable. The app loads correctly but I am getting `[Network error]: Network request failed`. So having researched all I could, I changed `localhost` to my computer's IP address, so the endpoint I am trying is now `http://192.168.20.75:3000/graphql`. However I am still getting the same error.

Xcode output is also showing `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.20.75:3000/graphql`.

The IP address is correct, as that's what I see in system preferences network section and also I can see that when React Native is loading the JS, it tells me it's "Loading from 192.168.20.75:8081". When I ran `ifconfig` I also see `inet 192.168.20.75 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.20.255`. I also tried `192.168.20.255` FWIW and no luck.

A different React Native app I worked on a couple of years ago worked when I had did this so I am really stumped trying to work out why this isn't working. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!